# Writing WAV to a file

Tags: java, file, mod-rewrite

I am currently working on a project that is asking me to use a pause from my parameters. Then write the new sound to a file, but every time i play my new file is only plays the last words. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public void play(int pause, String filename, String path) throws InterruptedException {
    // play the words in order
    for (int i = 0; i < numWords; i++) {
        myWordArray[i].blockingPlay();
        Thread.sleep(pause);
        try {
        myWordArray[i].writeToFile("C:\\Users\\Taylor\\Desktop\\JavaMedia\\thisisatest_pause.wav\\");
        } catch (SoundException e){
        System.out.println("Error" +e);

      }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please write the question according to the standards from: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It looks like you're writing on the same file, so just the last words is been saved. Instead, you should change the name of the wav file adding the index of the array, for example, to save a file for each word.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
myWordArray[i].writeToFile("C:\\Users\\Taylor\\Desktop\\JavaMedia\\thisisatest_pause.wav");
```

You see, you are iterating a list of WAV (?) objects; and you then you write all those different objects into the **same** file. Probably overwriting what was written before!

One easy way to fix that: include the index *i* in the created filename, like ending the thing with

```
"...pause-" + i + ".wav"
```

instead.

Comment: I figured that was the case, I tried what you said and it won't compile. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try {
                myWordArray[i].writeToFile("Users/rdopler/Documents/Mediasources/thisisatest_pause1" + i++ ".wav");
            } catch (SoundException e) {
                System.out.println("Error" + e);

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my answer - you are already increasing your counter, so you just need "+ i + " in order to add the counter value into the file name as string. Hope that works for you. But seriously: if you have problems on such a level, then you better spent some time studying the **java basics** first. There is no sense in saving WAV files if you dont know how to build strings and overcome such simple typos.